# Nifi PutSNS - Size Exceeds 256KB

Tags: apache-nifi, amazon-sns

I'm using a PutSNS processor which puts JSON (from API call) into SNS, in some cases JSON is more than 256KB, and I get "Size exceeds AWS SNS Limit of 256KB". Is there a way to chunk this into smaller sets?

Comment: why it's related to Nifi ?

Comment: Edited my question to make it clear.

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Nifi-PutSNS-Size-Exceeds-256KB/td-p/303291#M221508